# Can I put comments in a sftp batch file script?

Tags: linux, batch-file, sftp

I'm using sftp batch scripts to automate some file transfers.

Is there a syntax for putting comments in the batch files?

For example:

```
sftp -b mybatchscript.sftp nick@server
```

Where `mybatchscript.sftp` contains:

```
cd mydir
get *.txt
get *.dat
```

I'd like to have something similar to:

```
cd mydir
# Fetch all text files
get *.txt
# Fetch all data files
get *.dat
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Ok - it turns out that my guess at a commenting format works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on the sftp server, but with mine using # Whatever as a comment works fine just like you wrote.  If it doesn't, you could always do that and just process that file with grep:

```
grep -v '^#' myBactchScriptNotes.sftp > myBatchScript
```

Answer (score 2):

The commands are interpreted by an SFTP client, so it depends on the client, not a server (contrary to the answer by @KyleBrandt).

With the OpenSSH `sftp` (the most widespread one), lines starting with the `#` are indeed ignored.

```
# Download text files
get *.txt
```

It does not seem to be documented in the `sftp` man page, but it follows (documented) convention from [OpenSSH configuration files such as `sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config):

> Lines starting with `#' and empty lines are interpreted as comments.